# Blender Animation running very slow in viewport, but only occasionally

Tags: animation, rigging, 3d-view, frame-rate

this is my first post!
This seems like a question that has been asked many times but I can't find an answer to my exact problem.

For me, sometimes, the animation in the viewport has extremely low fps, like 2-7. Even when there are no keyframes set! I have been experiencing this with the Rain Rig, simpler scenes or rigs usually work fine when the issue occurs, but do have some fps drops that normally are not there. I need to fix this problem because I use the Rain Rig for university work and sometimes waste a lot of time.

By "sometimes" I mean, that it does not happen all the time. When restarting my laptop and generally trying around, I somehow manage to fix it, but I never know how I fixed it. Last time it took me about an hour. But when I do fix it, everything is working really smooth and fast, even with a ton of keyframes.

I think it might be some problem with my laptop? But I really don't know what it could be and I'm starting to go crazy, so I hope someone can help me out. Is there anyone that knows what could cause this problem?

It was requested to show that I use GPU for rendering:

[image]

Comment: You might want to see how much RAM and GPU Memory is available to you at restart time and when you begin your Blender Session.  The OS can tell you this.  If you feel comfortable you might want state some machine characteristics.  I sometimes close as many applications as possible if I am concerned about performance times or ... preventing crashes.

Comment: Computers (all of them) have a limit. If very likely that your laptop is not capable of processing data fast enough to sustain whatever framerate you think you can get out of it. It all depends on how complex your scene is, the number of vertices, etc... To assess the pacing of animation use wireframe rendering or try to render a preview render in low resolution.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Thank you for answering! my laptop has 30GB Ram, has a ryzen 9 prozessor and a  NVIDIA RTX 2070 Graphics card, so I think it should be fine running the scene. Especially since the scene does run really smoothly when I manage to fix it, so I think there must be some other mistake. When I check the laptops info rn, it says I have 31,9GB left out of 32GB. The rain scene without any keyframes is at 10 out of 24fps right now. What exactly do you mean with OS btw, sorry I'm a noob when it comes to laptops and all this stuff.

Comment: Please include a  Blender screen capture indicating you have chosen to use your GPU.  You might also want to state whether you have simple scenes that run at 24 fps.  You can also create more complex scenes progressively.  If you do not render part of a scene .. such as hair .. or grass you get more measurements of low demand files.  I have no idea of what is the [Rain Rig]

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I added a screen capture. And yes, simple scenes do run at 24 fps as they should. However, as I said, the problem is not that my laptop cannot handle it, since it can. There seems to be some other issue, like the graphics card not always working right. For example, I restarted my laptop today and now it works fine. Only when I have both characters active it drops down to 15fps, but never to the 2-7 fps I sometimes get when opening the scene! 
The Rain Rig is a free Character provided by the Blender Cloud.

Comment: It could be that you have a lot of other programs that start up with your pc, if you right click on your task bar > go to task manager (this is on windows). In the startup tab you can see how much influence each app has on start up.

Comment: @Alexbries cannot say it enough, my laptop CAN handle it. It just sometimes has some issues for some reason